# How to use the unique tag in an xsd file within a complex type?

Tags: xml, xsd, uniqueidentifier

I have seen examples on how to use the unique tag directly in an element declaration in an xsd, but I cannot figure out how to put into an element declaration that is a complextype, see the code below:

```
<xs:complexType name="flighttype">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="departure" type="departuretype"/>
    <xs:element name="arrival" type="arrivaltype"/>
    <xs:element name="altitude" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="speed" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="distance" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="entertainment" type="entertainmenttype"/>
    <xs:element name="safetymessage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="airline" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="flightno" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="model" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="passengers" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to make the id a unique id, I can get the following example to work, but its used directly within an element declaration.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870730/xml-element-unique-id-schema-repersentation)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XSD, identity constraints are associated with elements, not with types.  So define the identity constraint on the element(s) in your schema defined as having type `flighttype`, not on `flighttype` itself.